# Loading ng-src images with webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am loading an image with angular, e.g.

```
<img ng-src="{{::path-to-image}}"/>
```

When I bundle my application with webpack the image URL is resolved in runtime, thus not bundled by webpack's loaders.

This is the image loader I am using:

```
  {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    loader: 'url?limit=8192!img'
  }
```

How can webpack bundle those images resolved in runtime?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because I also needed thus functionality and found the original answer was far from a perfect solution I ended up figuring it out on my own.

Write a function in the controller:

```
$scope.loadImage = function(image) {
    return require('/images/' + image);
};
```

And use it in your ng-src:

```
<img ng-src="{{loadImage('myImage')}}" />
```

After that to make dynamic requires work you can use a [context](http://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html).

For example:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/require.context#examplejs

Comment: Clever solution! Thanks for sharing

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Thanks again

Comment: You missed the `{{ }}` in `ng-src`

Comment: You are right! Thanks for the feedback, I fixed it.

Comment: Don't like this solution, a controller shouldn't do anything, DOM related.

Comment: Why it is DOM related? What's the difference between loading for example json files or images?

Answer (score 10):

If you need an image path that is programmatically generated, it means you have some logic expecting this image to exist. In other words, you should consider this image as a dependency of that piece of logic, thus you need to require it explicitely.

In your JS code (eg: controller)

```
this.imageUrl = require('path-to-image' + someDynamicValue + '.jpg');
```

In your template:

```
<img ng-src="{{::myCtrl.imageUrl}}"/>
```

Webpack is smart enough to understand the dynamic `require` statement and bundle your images that will match that expression. 
Check the documentation for more details: https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html)

Comment: Your suggestion spreads view logic in the controller, which was previously unaware of if & how the view (the html file) presented the data. It feels more like a WebPack limitation for me, i.e. it can't handle resources that are resolved in runtime. I guess I will resort back to gulp for copying my static assets to the dist/ folder. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, and I have mixed feelings about this. But actually Webpack can handle it (through a require() call as I showed it). It is more a html-loader limitation as it doesn't take into account angular expression in src (or ng-src) attribute.

Comment: One more word: by relying on external tool to copy/build assets, you're hiding the dependency between your code (html) and the image. 
To me it's like using $ on the global scope (and expecting it's already defined at that point)  instead of explicitly requiring it with `var $ = require('jquery');`
We're not used to think like this for that kind of assets (fonts, images, styles) but after all, that what css and other file loaders are made for.

Comment: I agree, but it boils down to the loader again. If I configure the loader to hash the file contents then I can't reflect that in the html. On the other hand I don't want to configure the loader differently for images that are referenced statically and dynamically, plus the overhead on other developers. This type of "global" dependency keeps my code base and dev process simpler

Comment: what does that prefix of "::"?

Comment: This is one time biding. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding

Answer (score 2):

I created a `uiImage` directive which `requires` the images.

```
 function uiImage() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var src = attr.uiImage || attr.src;

        function loadImage(image) {
          return require(`Images/${image}`);
        }

        // required for webpack to pick up image
        element.attr('src', loadImage(src));
      }
    };
  }

  uiImage.$inject = [];
  export default uiImage;
```

Usage:

```
<img ui-image='myimage.png' />
```

webpack.config.js

I have a Webpack resolve `Images` which points to the location of all my images.

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
   'Images': path.join(config.appDir, '/images')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to dynamically resolve images at runtime with hashes generated by webpack, e.g., `imgA.bd79a5ba.png`.

```js
{
  test: /\.png$/,
  loader: 'file-loader?name=images/[name].[hash].[ext]',
}
```

I ended up creating a module to alias and required the images:

```
let map = {
  'imgA': require('./images/imgA.png'),
  'imgB': require('./images/imgB.png'),
  'imgC': require('./images/imgC.png')
}
```

This produces the map:

```
{
  'imgA': imgA.bd79a5ba.png,
  'imgB': imgB.e51f66a2.png,
  'imgC': imgC.d84ae37c.png
}
```

In my component I resolved the url from the map:

```
self.link = function link(scope) {
  scope.imageUrl = function(name) {
    function return map[name];
  }
};
```

It was then trivial to load the image:

```
 <img ng-src="{{ imageUrl('imgA') }}">
```

The above is simplified. I found it useful to create a module for the map:

```
export default {
  'imgA': require('./images/imgA.png'),
  'imgB': require('./images/imgB.png'),
  'imgC': require('./images/imgC.png')
}
```

then import it into the component module:

```
import urlMap from './imageUrlMap'
console.log(urlMap.imgA)

> imgA.bd79a5ba.png
```

Answer (score 0):

im just using CopyWebpackPlugin and no overhead at all

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
// WriteFilePlugin  needed only for webpack 3-4 and webpack dev-server
const WriteFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');
plugins: [
  ...
  new WriteFilePlugin(),
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {from: 'files', to: 'files'},
        {from: 'images-2x', to: 'images-2x'},
        {from: 'images', to: 'images'},
      ]),
]
```